# UrlRequest hanging on GET

Tags: python, macos, kivy

I am attempting to run a UrlRequest and Kivy does not seem to be wanting to return. It hangs until I force quit the app. I am able to run the same query through Rested and can verify the URL / Headers are correct.

I am new to Mac OS, is it being blocked by Firewall? Are there any logs I can check?

CODE

```
server_headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + str(self.hass_server_token), 'content-type': 'application/json'}                
request = UrlRequest(str(self.hass_server_url) + ':' + str(self.hass_server_port) + '/api/states', req_headers= server_headers, verify=False)
while not request.is_finished:
    Clock.tick()
self.hass_all_states = request.result
```

Thanks

Comment: The kivy internal request model works quite well https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.network.urlrequest.html it makes sure the main thread is not blocked while the request is executed.

Comment: PalimPalim, thanks for the help. I am using the onboarding UrlRequest to Kivy.

Comment: Can you make it into a minimal example, which includes all the imports etc. Ideally I would like to copy and paste your code. Run it on my machina and then see what is the priblem.

Answer (score 1):

Kivy's `UrlRequest` is threaded by default. This means you need to specify a callback functions for when the requests finishes successfully. It runs in the background so it doesn't block anything else your app is doing, which is why you have to specify the callback function in the `UrlRequest` call, so it knows what to do when it's done. Do this by passing the name of your callback function to the `on_success` parameter in your `UrlRequest`. Analogously, you can specify callback functions for `on_error` and `on_failure`.

Example:

```
def success_callback(self, *args):
    print(args)
```

Then later in your code:

```
UrlRequest('some_server_url', on_success=self.success_callback)
```

(You don't need to assign a variable to the `UrlRequest` like you were doing).

Comment: Does the threading explicitly act differently on MacOs? The REST call works fine on Windows and Android, just not Mac oddly enough. I will try using the on_success method to see if I get anywhere different. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't know of any explicit differences - I use MacOS myself and it works perfectly fine for me. Definitely need to use the `on_success` parameter though. If it's still not working, try the `on_error` and `on_failure` functions and print the `args` that you get, it'll tell you if there's an error.